# forms - Checkboxes in PDF forms are not printed using Firefox

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, printing, forms

Recently I started to prepare a larger PDF form in LaTeX. I checked the PDF output in Acrobat Reader and subsequently in various web browsers.

I noticed, that a `\CheckBox` in a form will not show up in the print preview and actual print output when using the current Firefox version (v117, Windows 10 at the time of writing). Acrobat Reader and Microsoft Edge seems not affected.

I was able to reproduce the issue using the small form below.
The only approach, that seems to work is wrap the `\CheckBox` in a `\fbox` to keep the box in the print output.

Is the `\fbox` overlay still the (only) way to go to make checkboxes printable?

Compare [Latex forms: Place label on the right side of checkbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446934/latex-forms-place-label-on-the-right-side-of-checkbox). Also applied in answer in [Making Hyperref Form CheckBox visible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392915/making-hyperref-form-checkbox-visible).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\section{PDF Form Test}
\begin{flushleft}
    Printed on FF
\end{flushleft}
\begin{Form}
    \fboxsep=0pt
    \fboxrule=0.9pt
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        \TextField{Name}\\\\
        \CheckBox[name=cb-normal,width=1em]{Check}\\\\
        \\\\
        \CheckBox[name=cb-style,width=1em,height=1em,borderstyle=S,bordercolor={red},backgroundcolor=lightgray]{Check} \\\\
        \\\\
        \fbox{\CheckBox[name=cb-fb,width=1em,height=1em,bordercolor={red}]{\ignorespaces}} fbox checkbox
    \end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well you could try the checkbox command from pdfmanagement-testphase (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/588555/2388) they use appearances (explicit images) but basically form fields are special objects in the PDF and if the pdf viewer doesn't properly support them there is not much you can do.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the pointer to the pdfmanagement-testphase package. Will have a look. Interestingly for normal text fields the output is okay (including border). Yes it is up to the pdf viewer to render the checkboxes properly.